# Secure Flask folder in directory

Tags: javascript, python, security, flask

So I have a website with a python/flask backend and a javascript/html/css frontend. The files in the directory look something like this:

```
__init__.py
application.py
templates
   - index.html
   - about.html
   - login.html
   - dashboard.html
   - ...
static
   - images
      - logo.png
      - ...
   - styles
      - ...
secret_git_directory
```

The public website is designed to have a secured login (hashed/salted passwords, etc.) to the dashboard. I want the login-protected dashboard to be able to access the contents of secret_git_directory that is from another git repository while keeping it secure from any attackers.

So my questions:

- Does python/flask hide this folder from being able to be viewed by users of the website? (I know that the *static* files are viewable but unsure about this directory)
- What are some steps to make sure that this secret_git_directory and its contents are secure?

Answer (score 0):

Flask sites are served up using routes. So in your dashboard route, as long as you can verify that a user had been authenticated and is authorized to access the dashboard, you can decide to serve up whatever "content" from the secret_git_directory or not depending on different levels of permission. And as long as you don't have Apache or nginx serve up the secret_git_directory folder by some other configurations, your folder is protected